# Error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Visual Studio Community for Mac `7.3.3 (build 7)` I make an iOS project. Then make a new .NET Standard 2.0 lib.

Using the built in NuGet support I add `Xamarin.Forms`to each Project.

In the Net Standard 2.0 Lib I `Add -> New File` and Select `Forms ContentPage Xaml`

This creates an empty class and corresponding XAML file. In the classes constructor it contains 1 line:

`InitializeComponent();`

When I attempt to compile either the NET Standard 2.0 lib OR the iOS project, the compilation fails with the following error:

> Error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

I have added no other code or dependencies to either project. Clearly I have missed something that is not obvious to me.

Comment: That's not really an error and you should be able to run without problem. Check the build action of xaml and make sure it's set to EmbeddedResource. Next open both xaml page and xaml.cs save and rebuild. This should help to remove the error message.

Comment: Deleting the App.xaml file worked for me, remeber to backup always!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As DeveloperX said in the comments, open the property window on your XAML file and make sure **Build Action** = `Embedded Resource` and the  make sure **Custom Tool** = `MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml`.

Finally, to fix a .NET Standard bug in VS add the following to your .NET Standard .csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55591 -->
  <None Remove="**\*.xaml" />

  <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you are still having problems, then it may be an issue with how the .NET Standard project was setup. Check out the following article which talks about converting a PCL to .NET Standard, which is what we did.

[Link](https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/)

Comment: I have had this component not found issue off and on for years and it took lots of wrangling, searching and usually reverting back to old versions etc to get passed it. Setting the Build Action and Custom Tool is magic. Would give you 2 upvotes if I could - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Close any open code behinds or open xaml files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have moved your code to different folder.
You can delete folder .vs in your project (this folder is hide) and reopen your project.